# Jquery datatable: add rows from database in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have a page that makes an Ajax call to a database on page load. It returns a list of companies that the user is following and then iterates the list trough and does another Ajax call to each company, to get some statistics about them. The statistics are then added to a Datatable which is being drawn quite a few times:

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../json/stats.aspx?t=followed-companies",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "../json/stats.aspx?t=company-stats" + "&n=" + data[i]
                    }).done(function (dataSecondary) {

       var stringtest = "<tr><td>" + dataSecondary.Stats1 + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + dataSecondary.Stats2 + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + dataSecondary.Stats3 + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + '<button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs dt-delete">' + "Delete" + "</td></tr>";
                        table.row.add($(stringtest)).draw();
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log('error', xhr);
            }
        });
```

I do not have much experience in programming, but I do know that this takes ages to load and so has a very poor performance.

**Main question is, can I use the table.draw(); after I have added the rows in that loop?** I guess that could save some time. I tried to draw the table after the loop is finished but the table said that there is no data to show.

Second question, is this bad practise (mainly those nested Ajax calls with loops and SQL queries), and should I try to unify as many SQL queries as possible?

Comment: I think it's bad practice. Your loop basically says 'hit the database every single time'. That's going to take ages to load. Why not try getting all the things you want once in an array or something and then display them in any way you want?

I'm pretty sure a for loop with ajax calls will kneel your website's speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/roycode/zq902hup/21/)** - Get Post Data using ajax and display in .dataTable()

**Main question is, can I use the table.draw(); after I have added the rows in that loop?**

Yes you can. If you look at the docs of [datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) you'll see that the draw() function is made for that.

> When you perform an action such as adding or deleting a row, changing
>   the sorting, filtering or paging characteristics of the table you'll
>   want DataTables to update the display to reflect these changes. This
>   function is provided for that purpose.

**Second question, is this bad practise (mainly those nested Ajax calls with loops and SQL queries), and should I try to unify as many SQL queries as possible?**

Yes it's bad practice to have many calls going to your backend. If you have control over the backend, you should aim to optimise it. For example: When you supply a list of companies, it will return the stats for all those companies specified.

Currently it will especially be a bad experience for those with a slow internet connection e.g. mobile users.

Also, this solution doesn't scale well. Imagine your website taking off and 100s of individuals are using it simultaneously. That means 100 * amount-of-followed-companies calls, while with the suggested it would be 100 calls to the backend for fetching the same data.

Have you also considered the possibility to generate a table using [ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax).

**UPDATE:**
As for the draw() function that is not working. According to the docs, you provide the data structure without actually building the table with html yourself. Use the data returned instead where columnNameX is the name of the columns you specified. Give this a try in your .done().

```
var data = {
  columnName1: dataSecondary.Stats1
  columnName2: dataSecondary.Stats2 
  columnName3: dataSecondary.Stats3
}

table.row.add(data).draw();
```

As for generating the button. I haven't worked with them before but you can find more about them [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons).

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I will be looking in to the optimization part now that I got this working. How ever, the .draw() does not work if it is not inside the loop.

Comment: Do you receive an error message? Try the updated part of my answer.

Comment: I've added a link to a working example. You'll find the link at the top of the answer. Check also the console log of the jsfiddle. Data returned from the ajax call is logged there too, so you know what comes back from the server.

Comment: The reason I could not use draw outside the loop was because of the asynchronous Ajax call.